# Cloudwatch alarm for ec2 launching without specific tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I am trying to set an cloutwatch alarm, if any new ec2 instance without specific tag assigned to it while launching. Checked the cloudwatch metric but seems there is no such alarm pre-exist

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can add some screenshots or links to docs that you are using so we can better understand.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure the alarm using the Cloudwatch dashboard.

[image]